# I have passed a numpy.ndarray as a parameter to face_recognizer.predict () but still getting error as The function/feature is not implemented)

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to detect multiple faces from an image and i passed a ndarray to the predict function of LBPHFaceRecognizer but I get an error as

`OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\lbph_faces.cpp:265: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Using Original Local Binary Patterns for feature extraction only works on single-channel images (given 2344). Please pass the image data as a grayscale image! in function 'cv::face::elbp'`

Comment: What is the `.shape` of the array you are passing in? Is it single-channel/greyscale as the error suggests?

Answer (score 0):

You are likely passing a batch of images, not a single image. For the `np.array` that you are passing as input, check its dimensions by printing `inputArray.shape`. It should be something like (height, width, 1) or (height, width). If it is (height, width, 2344), then that is your issue, as you are passing an array of 2344 images instead of a single image. You can try passing `inputArray[:,:,i]` to input the ith image.

Comment: Thank you. I tried and got the result as (1, 294, 294)

Comment: Hmm, that does not seem to follow openCV's expected (height, width, channel) order. Regardless, we want to pass the grayscale image without the channel dimension, so try passing `inputArray[0,:,:]` instead of `inputArray`